# Invalid Syntax on filterset_fields inside Viewset when I try to add necessary paranthesis

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class PublicUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
    filterset_fields = {'id','username','deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte']}
```

When I give it a go with below parameter,it works:

```
    filterset_fields = ['id','username','deliveredtotime']
```

It also works with

```
    filterset_fields = {'deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte']}
```

But when I try to do as shown below:

```
    filterset_fields = {'id','username','deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte']}
```

I get this:

**Error:**

```
filterset_fields = {'id','username','deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte']}

SyntaxError: invalid syntax ':'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Note: I know this is **NOT** a valid dictionary parameter. But I have looked at
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/
and didn't see any valid option. Does someone know how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a list of fields, The *Django filters* turns it into a dictionary with the `DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR` as lookups.

So we can work with:

```
from django_filters.conf import settings

filterset_fields = {
    'id': [settings.DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR],
    'username': [settings.DEFAULT_LOOKUP_EXPR],
    'deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte'],
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
from django_filters.conf import settings

filterset_fields = {
    'id': ['exact'],
    'username': ['exact'],
    'deliveredtotime': ['gte', 'lte'],
}
```

but thus would allow Django filters to later change that.

It thus will filter on these fields only with the `exact` filter.